# Slider using CarouFredSel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, caroufredsel

I am trying to use a slider for my webpage and i cant get it. I am trying CarouFredSel Slider. I am a beginner and trying to make a webpage via Youtube Video.

This is my main.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

"use strict";
$('#slider-carousel').carouFredSel({
    responsive:true,
    width:'100%',
    circular:true,
    scroll:{
            items:1,
            duration:500,
            pauseOnHover:true;
    },
    auto:true;
    items:
    {
        visible:{
            min:1,
            max:1;
        },
        height:"variable"
    },
    pagination:{
        container:".sliderpager",
        pageAnchorBuilder:false
    }
});
```

})

The youtube video i am currectly using is ,

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RHj5bdrfCr8&t=614s

And i downloaded "jquerycarouFredSel-6.2.1-packedjs" file from

https://github.com/Codeinwp/carouFredSel-jQuery

Answer (score 1):

> You have syntax errors in the code, check below:
>
> don't use ; in the options

```
$('#slider-carousel').carouFredSel({
    responsive:true,
    width:'100%',
    circular:true,
    scroll:{
            items:1,
            duration:500,
            pauseOnHover:true
    },
    auto:true,
    items:
    {
        visible:{
            min:1,
            max:1
        },
        height:"variable"
    },
    pagination:{
        container:".sliderpager",
        pageAnchorBuilder:false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are new beginner than you should use slick slider. Its very simple. Hope you will implement it. I will share you a link.

https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/